# why hibernate does not insert repititive value of ArrayList in database table

Tags: hibernate, arraylist, mapping

i have a employee class that conaint a List from Certificate class. when i save employee class to the database hibernate pass up insert repititive element to database. following is my mapping file detail :

```
<hibernate-mapping package="ir.imrasta.hibernate.sample4">
<class name="Employee" table="employee">
    <meta attribute="class-description">
        This class contains employee detail.
    </meta>
    <id name="id" type="int" column="id" >
        <generator class="native" />
    </id>
    <list name="certificates" cascade="all"  lazy="false">
        <key column="employee_id" />
        <list-index column="idx" />
        <one-to-many class="Certificate"/>
    </list>
    <property name="firstName" type="string" column="first_name" />
    <property name="lastName" type="string" column="last_name" />
    <property name="salary" type="int" column="salary" />
</class>

<class name="Certificate" table="list_certificate">
    <meta attribute="class-description">
        This class contains certificate records.
    </meta>
    <id name="id" type="int" column="id" >
        <generator class="native" />
    </id>
    <property name="name" type="string" column="certificate_name" />
</class>
```

i use following code for add Employee object to database:

```
ManageEmployee me=new ManageEmployee();
List<Certificate> lst1=new ArrayList<Certificate>();
lst1.add(new Certificate("MCA"));
Certificate a=new Certificate("MBA");
lst1.add(a);
lst1.add(new Certificate("PMP"));
lst1.add(a);
int id1=me.addEmployee(new Employee("Ali","Habibi",200,lst1));
```

but when i do select query in certificate table, i get following result:

```
+------+--------------------+--------+--------------+  
|  id  | certificate_name   |  idx   | employee_id  |  
+------+--------------------+--------+--------------+  
|  81  | MCA                |       1|           164|  
+------+--------------------+--------+--------------+  
|  82  | MBA                |       4|           164|  
+------+--------------------+--------+--------------+  
|  83  | PMP                |       3|           164|  
+------+--------------------+--------+--------------+
```

Comment: what's wrong with that? you add employee with 3 certificate and you got that right in your table

Comment: in list the certificate MBA is repititve. my list have 4 element. but repititived element not inserted in table. this means if i have repititive element hibernate pass up it?

Comment: yes because 1 object of entity = 1 row, if you want to add it to 2 row with the same value then you need to make 2 object with the same value(see my answer). Then hibernate will generate new id for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

that is because you add multiple time with the same object like this :

```
Certificate a=new Certificate("MBA");
lst1.add(a);
lst1.add(new Certificate("PMP"));
lst1.add(a);
```

if you want MBA to be add 2 times you need to insert it like this :

```
lst1.add(new Certificate("MBA"));
lst1.add(new Certificate("PMP"));
lst1.add(new Certificate("MBA"));
```

when you save same value to list:

```
List l = new ArrayList();
Integer a = new Integer(1);
l.add(a);
l.add(a);
l.add(new Integer(1));
l.add(new Integer(1));
```

`l.get(0)` and `l.get(1)` is the same object(have 1 object id), but `l.get(2)` and `l.get(3)` is a different object that have different id although have the same value. the object brought by this list is only 3, with 4 different door.

Comment: ok. then can i say that if i have repititive element (i override equals method of Certificate, if two object have same name are equal) in my ArrayList. hibermate pass up Repititived element and store it once?

Comment: but if it is true wht is diferent between Set and List. i think List most allow to store repititived Element.

Comment: thank you. i read your last comment in  my question and get my answer. when object refrence is difference it add new record. thanks.

Comment: list does't duplicate its element, let me explain to you in my answer latter